# Как быть с годом, выраженным десятичной дробью?

Tags: согласование

Только что поправила в тексте  *в течение 4,5 лет* (действителен документ) на *4,5 года...*

Спохватилась; пишу патронессе, мол, отмените правку, собственноручно ляп внесла! Какие могут быть у года десятые; это ж с калькулятором не рассчитаешь...

Отвечает: но можно же прочесть и как *четыре с половиной года.*

Знаю, что нельзя, а правила найти не могу. Помогите, люди добрые!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Галина, Вы исправили правильно, добавьте слово "части": в течение четырех и пяти десятых части (чего?) года. Существительное после дроби ставится в единственном числе, управляется пропущенным словом "части, доли", а если ЛЕТ, то тогда надо словами писать "четырёх с половиной лет".

Comment: Годы и сутки принято дробить долями в другой системе счисления, двенадцатеричной, и в тексте всякий увидит в пятёрке только половину года, как бы не писать — словами или цифрами.

Comment: shampar, *как бы НИ писать"... )))

Comment: Люсенька, опечатка? "В течение четырех и пяти десятых части (чего?) года" - частей?

Comment: Конечно - частей, долей

Answer (score 2):

> 4,5 года

Четыре и пять десятых **года**, четыре с половиной **года**. В чем ляп? 
Если к чему и придираться, то править на "4 года и шесть месяцев", но большого смысла в том нет (если это не приговор суда - там да, страхуются от прочтения *калькуляторофобами*).

А, там падеж при "в течение"... Пардон.
Тогда да, **в течение четырех с половиной лет**, но все равно **в течение четырех и пяти десятых года**. Лет - счетная форма для слова "год", но здесь-то она не нужна. Так что вы с "патронессой" что-то обе в падежах запутались.

Comment: Мне правило нужно! Как быть с десятичной дробью, если целое не десять? Может, перевести в обыкновенную дробь - 4 ½?

Comment: *Как быть с десятичной дробью* - никак. Чем она вам мешает? Что такое "целое не десять"? Сформулируйте, на что именно правило? Как дроби читаются? Да так и читаются, Х целых и Y десятых (года, яблока, землекопа).

Comment: Целое — 1 (12 месяцев), половина целого — 0,5 (6 месяцев), четверть целого — 0,25 (3 месяца). Вы, покупая яблоки, считаете же их количество. Но Вас же не смущает при этом, что одно может весить 50 грамм, а другое 60? Масса для Вас роли не играет. Так и здесь количество дней или месяцев не запрещает взять год за 100% и вычислять 50%, 25% от него, если нужно.

Comment: @Третийглаз да это все так, но я не думаю, что тут проблема именно с математикой... Конечно, у года, как и у месяца, скажем, может быть и половина и треть... Но по контексту можно заключить, что проблема всё-таки в выборе грамматической формы или одного слова или всей синтаксической конструкции.. Вот в чем именно - никак понять не могу.

Comment: @Morkovkin я не вижу в тексте никакой проблемы, но если Вы или кто-либо сможет её сформулировать,подумаем над решением вместе.

Comment: @ТретийГлаз Проблема - у автора ))) Автор хочет какого-то правила, а я не понимаю, на какой случай.